# Data not being passed to the server from Datatables

Tags: datatables, grails-plugin

I have a really simple Datatable configuration,

```
 $("#providerTable").dataTable({
        "bLengthChange":false,
        "bAutoWidth":false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide":true,
        "sAjaxSource":"${createLink(controller: 'authorization', action: 'fetchProvider')}" ,
        "bInfo": true,
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
        },
        "fnInfoCallback": function( oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre ) {
            return ("Showing " + iStart +" to "+ iEnd + " of " + iTotal);
        }
    });
```

Everything is working fine except that the variable `more_data` that should have been passed to the server is not passed. I'm using Grails at the server side and a quick parameter dump from the Ajax request gives the following result:

```
wrappedMap=[iSortCol_0:0, sSearch_2:, bRegex:false, sSearch_3:, sSearch_0:, sSearch_1:, sSearch:, iSortingCols:1, mDataProp_0:0, mDataProp_1:1, mDataProp_2:2, mDataProp_3:3, mDataProp_4:4, bSortable_2:true, bSortable_1:true, bSortable_4:true, bSortable_3:true, bSortable_0:true, sColumns:, iColumns:5, _:1347175565036, sSearch_4:, bRegex_2:false, bSearchable_2:true, bSearchable_1:true, bRegex_3:false, bSearchable_0:true, bRegex_4:false, sSortDir_0:asc, iDisplayStart:0, iDisplayLength:10, sEcho:1, bSearchable_4:true, bRegex_0:false, bSearchable_3:true, bRegex_1:false, action:fetchProvider, controller:authorization]
```

see, there's no sign of the variable named `more_data`. All other default Datatable variables along with the controller and action name are being passed except for the `more_data` variable. What mistake could I be making here?

Thanks

Comment: what version of datatables are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fnServerParams is a new 1.8.2 interface. if you have 1.8.1 or earlier,
>   there is no fnServerParams

[Question about fnServerParams](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6600/question-about-fnserverparams/p1)

upgrade to a *1.8.2* or later in order to use the `fnServerParams`